# Log-likelihood for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, likelihood

So I'm reading Python Machine Learning by Sebastian Raschka, but I'm getting a little lost on an equation that appears multiple times in the book in two different forms.

Here it is with (y) and (1-y) as indicator functions:
[image]

It then appears in this form with the initial (y) indicator missing.  Where did it go?? Is it not important? My intuition tells me it needs to stay in the equation.
[image]

Lastly, here it is with an l2 penalty:
<< cannot post more than 2 links. sorry >>

Can anyone help explain this discrepancy?  What am I not understanding?

Comment: The second image looks like $y^{(i)}$ was lost through a typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

The $J$ seems to be an estimate of (a factor of the) the cross entropy term. So, you are right a $y^{(i)}$ is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is in fact an error.** I have the same book but the section now reads as the picture below.
[image]

You can also note in the prior section he's *maximizing a likelihood function*. He then moves to *minimizing a log-likelihood function*. As you can see in this picture the y(i) term is in the exponent. When he takes the log it moves to the front, thus the y(i) should be there.[image]